# Basic C Server: Connection Refused Error

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a program that should accept a connection at port 62085 and sends back a test message.  The code hangs at accept() and never returns even if the client tries to connect.  Why does the server refuse the connections?  Could it be a firewall problem?

This code works for me when compiled under OS X 10.8.3, but refuses connections when running on Oracle Enterprise Linux.  `accept()` will never accept a connection, and telnet to the port from another device gives  a `Connection Refused` error.  The below is output from netstat that proves the program is in fact listening on the port I want.  I have tried other ports, 62084, 666 and 8080 to see if there was something blocking that particular port.  (The netstat outputs were from two different commands).

```
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62085               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11815/del-chef  

   tcp        0      0 129.133.124.83:62085        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15101/del-chef
```

iptables shows that it is allowing connections on all ports as well.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:yo-main 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:terabase 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`
```

And the output of `sudo iptables -t mangle -L` is

the output of that command is

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Both the OS X device and Enterprise Linux Server are running on the same network, so I am befuddled as to why when I execute `telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 62085` I receive a `Connection Refused` error.

The relevant code is below:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define BACKLOG 10
#define PORT "62085"

void main() {
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;  // use IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res) != 0){
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "getaddrinfo() error");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error creating socket");
            continue;
        }
        int yes = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error settings socket options");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            close(sockfd);
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error binding socket");
            continue;
        }

        break;    
    }
    if (p == NULL){
        close(sockfd);
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error binding socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res); // free memory now that it is no longer in use

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1){
        close(sockfd);
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error listening");
        exit(1);
    }
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Waiting for connections");
    addr_size = sizeof(cli_addr);
    if (new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &addr_size) == -1){
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error accepting connection");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you phrase this as a question?

Comment: Could you format the code so that it compiles?

Comment: Added the includes etc.  it should now compile and work on anything but Windows (windows networking relies on different functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was iptables, issuing `service stop iptables` allowed the code to work.  I ended up adding the following rule to iptables:

`sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 62085 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown, so the problem is external to your app.  Since your socket is clearly listening and bas not exhausted its backlog yet, then the  connection refused error has to mean that the OS itself, or possibly/likely a firewall/router, is refusing the connection before it reaches your app.

Comment: What in the OS could be causing this?  I checked the SELinux logs and there was nothing there, and since iptables isn't the culprit, what else is there?

Comment: I'm betting it is a firewall/router issue. If you bind to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx instead of 0.0.0.0, do you still have the same error?

Comment: @user2340872 are you absolutely sure its not iptables? Have you checked _sudo iptables -t mangle -L_ ?

Comment: @thuovila added the output of the command to my question, doesn't appear this is due to iptables

Comment: @RemyLebeau also tried binding to the IPv4 address and the same connection refused errors.

Comment: It was iptables, no idea why though.  It looks like it should have worked regardless based on my rules.